# Compare value of two arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Five random numbers(from numbers array) will be shown one by one and we need to recall last four number by clicking the number. The answers are push to answer array after clicking. Now i need to compare answers array and number array to calculate the score. My problem is in scoring logic which is not working as expected. When the first guess(or any guess) is correct, then all the remaining guess are also counted as correct even its not.

link: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-pascal-rh6e13?file=/src/App.js

Below is the score calculation logic

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (answers.length) {
      if (numbers[4].num === answers[3]) {
        console.log(
          "match is--------------------------------1",
          numbers[4].num,
          answers[3]
        );
        setScore(score=> score + 1);
      } else if (numbers[3].num === answers[2]) {
        console.log(
          "match is--------------------------------2",
          numbers[3].num,
          answers[2]
        );
        setScore(score=> score + 1);
      } else if (numbers[2].num === answers[1]) {
        console.log(
          "match is--------------------------------3",
          numbers[2].num,
          answers[1]
        );
        setScore(score=> score + 1);
      } else if (numbers[1].num === answers[0]) {
        console.log(
          "match is--------------------------------4",
          numbers[1].num,
          answers[0]
        );
        setScore(score=> score + 1);
      } else {
        console.log("no match---------------------");
      }
    }
  }, [answers, numbers]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to simplify your calculation logic with a loop like that:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Checking result", answers, numbers);
    if (answers.length < numbers.length - 1) {
        return;
    }
    let i = 0;
    while (i < numbers.length - 1) {
        if (numbers[i + 1].num === answers[i]) {
            console.log("match is--------------------------------1");
            setScore((score) => score + 1);
        }
        i++;
    }
}, [answers, numbers]);
```

Here you have a fork of your demo with the changes I describe below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-sara-zftstd?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate score doing sth like this:

```js
const myScore = useMemo(() => {
    let points = 0;
    const numbersToCompare = numbers.filter((_, index) => index > 0);
    for (let i in numbersToCompare) {
      if (numbersToCompare[i].num === answers[i]) {
        points = points + 1;
      }
    }
    return points;
  }, [answers, numbers]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The comparison of two arrays can be stored in a result array using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) , subsequently you can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to calculate a score.

Something like

```js
const arr = [...Array(5)]
  .map( _ => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 );
const fakeAnswer = [...Array(5)]
  .map( _ => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 );
const results = arr.map((v, i) => v === fakeAnswer[i]);
const score = results.reduce( (acc, val) => acc + +val, 0);
console.log(`random values [${arr}]`);
console.log(`fakeAnswer: [${fakeAnswer}]\nresults: [${
  results}]\nscore: ${score}`);
```